# Does an Indian citizen with a UK residence permit need a visa for Mexico?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, mexico, uk-residents

My husband has an Indian passport and has UK residency and was granted Leave to Remain in November 2016. We want to holiday in Cancun, Mexico in May 2017 for our anniversary. I am a British National. Does he need a Mexican visa and, if so, how does he go about obtaining one?

Comment: Not sure whether it makes a difference but what is your nationality (and if needed visa status)?

Comment: He does not have indefinite leave to remain but just leave to remain as he has just got that in November but would like to go to cancun in may next year

Answer (score 7):

> My husband has an Indian passport and has UK residency with Indefinite
>   Leave to Remain (ILR). Does he need a Mexican visa ?

NO visa required. Your husband can simply enter Mexico without a visa on a valid visa or permanent residence of UK.

Source:[Consulate General of Mexico](https://consulmex2.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico)

The answer is from official consulate general of Mexico in San Francisco:

" With the purpose of facilitating and promoting travel to Mexico, effective May 2016 all those foreign nationals, regardless of their nationality, visiting Mexico for tourism, business or transit are NOT required to obtain a Mexican visa IF they hold a valid (non-expired) **Visa or Permanent Residence** of any of this countries: **United States of America, Canada, Japan, United Kingdom or Schengen area (European Union)**."

However the length of stay is permitted for up to 180 days and visitors could be refused entry for  not holding return/onward tickets:

Source:[Visa And Passport](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/timatic.htm)

National India (IN)
Embarkation United Kingdom (GB)/Destination Mexico (MX)

Mexico (MX)

Passport required.
- Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
  valid on arrival.
Passport Exemptions:

- Passengers with an emergency or a temporary passport.

**Visa required, except for Passengers with a valid visa issued
by Canada, Japan, USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member
State For details, for a maximum stay of 180 days**. 
Minors:
- Passport not required for alien minors (up to/incl.17 years
  of age) registered in their parent/guardian passport,
  provided traveling with the passport holder. 
- All minors under 14 years of age, when traveling alone,
  should be met by an adult. 
Additional Information:

- A valid Mexican visa in an expired passport is accepted if
  the passenger also has a valid passport.
  Warning:
- Visitors not holding return/onward tickets For details, could be refused entry.

Answer (score 4):

I'm from the UK and my husband is a Moroccan citizen living in the UK on a spouse visa. We just returned from Mexico and had been advised by the Embassy to apply for a visa in advance, which we did. On arrival, we were questioned by Immigration for 1.5 hours before being allowed to enter the country. I'm not sure we would have gotten in without the visa.