# My partner has an Indian passport with a Tier 2 general visa and a multi-entry Schengen visa - do we need a visa to travel to mexico?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, mexico, uk-residents

My partner has an Indian passport with a Tier 2 general visa and a multi-entry Schengen visa. All websites I've looked at state he doesn't require a visa. We've had verbal confirmation from the Mexican consulate in India and written confirmation from a US consulate that he does not require one. However, the London consulate said they advise one.

We don't have time to get one, is there anything we should take to support entry to the country? Or will he not even be allowed on the flight?

Comment: We already have a couple of questions for this issue. The canonical one is [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82917/do-indian-passport-holders-with-uk-tier-2-need-to-get-a-tourist-visa-for-mexico) (for which I will raise a duplicate flag). But you should also see [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/88796/50234) on a separate question for slightly different circumstances

Comment: @RedBaron thank you. I feel like the rules are quite clear on this as per 2 consulates apart from the London one who are "advising" and warning of lots of cases of people being returned. I wondered if we take along all docs incl. return tickets, itinerary (hotel), bank statement, show cash to support and potentially something to prove there's a job to go back to if that would help us out there answering questions if needed?

Comment: As per rules you don't need a visa. So atleast the airlines will not deny you boarding. For the mexican immigration, it is really a game of chance. If you are fully prepared (return ticket, enough money and cast iron itinerary) I don't think you should face any hassle apart from a lengthy landing interview.

Comment: Thank you. We have no option to do a visa now so will just have to be fully prepared with docs and hope for the best.